# ARRAYFORMULA for MAX value doesn't work with N/A input

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am using an `ARRAYFORMULA` in column F to output the maximum of three values, in columns C, D and E. When C, D, and E are all numbers, the formula works perfectly. However, when any of C, D, or E are letters (i.e., `N/A` or `NA`) the formula breaks:

[image: example of break]

Here is the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:A=0,,IFERROR(1*IF(C2:C>D2:D,IF(C2:C>E2:E,C2:C,E2:E),IF(D2:D>E2:E,D2:D,E2:E)),0)))
```

How can I get it to work even when letters are present?

My desired result in the example above is **763**.

A [reproduction](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-mLnxQj95LmUyjY_z8Ylnb7SrZ7UUrWdLh-am7bV3w/edit?usp=sharing) of the problem.

Comment: @player0 added google sheet link to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(B2:F*1, 0)),
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 "max(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&"),", "")), ".\z", "")&"")), 
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]